# Is session maintained at server level for application

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, struts-1, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is it possible to save application or website session @serverside? Like every site has its own session and these are only valid for some time and these are maintained browser level and i want to know can we maintain session and store @server level that if browser stop support for cookies we don't face any issue at application

Comment: Server side session storage is possible, but usually works with a session-id stored in a *cookie*, so cookie-less is still a problem

Comment: @Hans thanks yes every user login with different session id but i issue is Mozilla's new update block all cookies so i try to save session on server side

Comment: That *is* where sessions are stored. Session IDs can also be passed in URLs.

Comment: Does *all* cookie support stop, or just for semi-permanent cookies and/or cookies from other domains? Session cookies are from the same site as the pages and usually have no expiry date, meaning they already disappear when the browser closes.

Comment: Just for semi-permanent cookies  and the same issue occur on Chrome even